# what transport to use for zend mail Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail or Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp

Tags: php, email, zend-framework, zend-mail

Could you please tell when to use  Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail and when to use  Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp for Zend Mail?
What are the benefits of one over another? What is better from the perfomance point of view, for example?
If I need to send many emails what is a better choice?
I use smpt server on linux server and Green Arrow Delivery System. I used Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp transport for a while (it seems to me a preferred way, correct me I'm wrong), but for some reason when I use Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp message id  header is not set by server, but it looks like it sets message id header if I use Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail.
Do you I have some limitations or perfomance (or scalability) penalties if I use  Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail over Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp?

Comment: I'd suggest you read about sendmail and SMTP in general.

Comment: Of course, I read about them, I wouldn't ask question otherwise. I would be greatful if give conrete answer if you are able to give it. Your comment is not helpful and doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325482/sendmail-vs-smtp

Comment: I saw it but I still questions. I didn't find conrete answer, for example, if send mail transport appropriate for sending many emails or not. Is any options suitable for me or not?